# Hibernate DDL issue. DB Tables tries to still generates tables in Spring Boot

Tags: database, hibernate

I have maybe an stupid issue, but dont know how to fix it.
I am generating in my Spring Boot Application Tables via Flyway. This works perfectly.

When starting my application i am seeing that the Flyway Scripts are running successfull, but then somehow Hibernate tries to generate again the Tables. Therefore i am getting following error:

```
hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table XXXX" via JDBC Statement
```

I already lookup how to switch off this. 
I was setting following parameter in my application.yaml

```
jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    generate-ddl: false
```

What i am doing wrong. How can i switch off the DLL generation of Hibernate.

Comment: do you have spring: above jpa: in application.yaml ?

Comment: Yes i have spring above jpa.